# Getting 'undefined' result when going through JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

I am making an AJAX request that return a JSON file, which I converted into an array using JSON.parse, however, when I try to go through some of the object's, I get 'undefined' as a result instead of the data from the JSON file.

```
    function loadData() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var armoryNews = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(armoryNews["armorynews"][0]);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.torn.com/faction/8819?selections=armorynews&key=XXXXXXXXXX", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

loadData();
```

Here's the JSON File I am requesting: https://pastebin.com/HGsxFcTM

I've tried other methods of getting this file, like jsonp, but these didn't work due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Thank You in advance

Comment: armorynews contains another object and not array, you need to access it by its keys and not by its index. `armoryNews['armorynews']['250852079']`.

Comment: Worked like a charm Lain, but is there a way to access these objects in any other way rather than their key?

Comment: If you want to iterate over the whole `armoryNews['armorynews']` dict, you can use a loop : `for (var key in armoryNews['armorynews']) { // do something with armoryNews['armorynews'][key] }`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you both

Comment: `Object.keys()` is another option. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var armoryNews = {
   "armorynews": {
      "250852079": {
         "timestamp": 1531570578,
         "news": "<a href = \"http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2143655\">3dubbeltjes<\/a> used one of the faction's Xanax items."
      },
      "250848543": {
         "timestamp": 1531567903,
         "news": "<a href = \"http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2072880\">Akine<\/a> used one of the faction's Xanax items."
      },
      "250847811": {
         "timestamp": 1531567248,
         "news": "<a href = \"http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2147631\">Silnt<\/a> used one of the faction's Bottle of Beer items."
      }
   }
};

var armorynewsKeys = Object.keys(armoryNews["armorynews"]);

armorynewsKeys.map(item => {
  console.log(armoryNews["armorynews"][item]);
});
```